# In a box, two flashlights face each other. How does the light which hits the side of the box vary with two lights in it instead of one light?

Tags: energy, visible-light

Does the light hitting the light affect the light which ultimately hits the side of the box? 
[image: https://i.postimg.cc/J73r2jKv/lights-in-box.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

If you are basically asking if the light beams interact with each other , the [answer is no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics), photon photon scattering is very improble. The light on the walls will be the sum of the two light beams.

There is a series of videos by an MIT professor using lasers that e[xplains by demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU) that light beams superimpose on each other, but do not interact to any measurable degree. Superposition can display interference patterns, but in the case of two flashlights the beams are incoherent . The energy dispersed is the same, so the only difference of having two flashlights instead of one will be that the shadows will mostly  disappear, a different shadow pattern, and there will be twice the illumination in the box.

Answer (score 1):

If the beams are mutually coherent (though two ordinary flashlights certainly would not be mutually coherent), the speckle patterns due to scattered light in the room  would be different from the simple sum of the intensities of the two beams.  However, for ordinary flashlights the light intensity at each point in the room would be the simple sum of the intensities of light from the two sources.

The two light beams in either case would simply pass through each other as if the other light beam were not there.